# using regex set in javascript object property

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to use regular expression which is set in javascript's object property, like below

```
var myObj = { mask : /([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|-|\.|\'|[&])/}
```

in some other function which will get `myObj` as parameter and in that function I need to test that if string contains any character **not matching** above regex. 
Example

```
function check(myObj , value){
//Want to code here to read myObj.mask and return false if value contains 
//any character not matching myObj.mask. as per above example if value contain any special character 
// like &#$% then i want to return false

}
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is very redundant, you are doing lots of unnecessary escaping. You can use the shorter version:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9-.'&])*$/
```

Notice I added some anchors, they are necessary for `RegExp.test()`;

```
var myObj = { mask : /^([a-zA-Z0-9-.'&])*$/ }

function check(myObj , value){
    return myObj.mask.test(value);
}

console.log(check(myObj, "abc1-.'&")); //true
console.log(check(myObj, "&#$%")); //false
console.log(check(myObj, "abc#")); //false
```

#### Explanation for `/^([a-zA-Z0-9-.'&])*$/`

- `^`                        the beginning of the string
- `(`                        group and capture start group 1
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-.'&]`          any character of: `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `0` to `9`, `-`, `.`, `'` or `&`
- `)`                       end of group 1
- `*` group 1 zero or more times
- `$`                        end of the
                         string

It is simpler than the original because `[a-z]|[A-Z]` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`. Also, inside character classes (that is, between `[` and `]`), you don't have to escape `.`, `'` or `&`.

## If you can't change the expression

In that case, we can create a new `RegExp` object, adapting the one passed as parameter.

```
var myObj = { mask : /([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|-|\.|\'|[&])/ }

function check(myObj , value){
    return new RegExp('^'+myObj.mask.source+'*$').test(value);
}

console.log(check(myObj, "abc1-.'&")); // true
console.log(check(myObj, "&#$%")); // false
console.log(check(myObj, "abc#")); // false
```

Comment: Would like to know a short explanation of your regex `/^([a-zA-Z0-9-.'&])*$/`

Comment: one doubt, what if `?` is used instead `*` will that not be okay?

Comment: @user1671639 I added some explanation. Can you check if it good enough?

Comment: I cannot change regex as per suggested, since it is coming from some where else. i just tested above code with input regex as `/([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|-|\.|\'|[&])/` and it returns true in all console logs

Comment: @rps Since I marked the start `^` and end `$` of strings, using `?` would allow only zero or one repetitions, that is, it would olny match strings like `""`, `"a"`, `"b"`... `"&"`.

Comment: `return new RegExp('^(' + myObj.mask.source + ')*$').test(value);`

Comment: got it, but if say I want to check(without the `^$`) if atleast one match is found, is using `?` okay or will it return true even if it won't find a single match? and why is `()` necessary, sorry I am not good at regex so having few many doubts.

Comment: @sagar check the new added snippet

Comment: @acdcjunior - Ya thats working, got it from  as well in above comment. Lots of thanks to you and Mics

Comment: @rps With `?` it will match nothing, so I guess it is not ok. Check this test: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/QFuxt/1/ (open console F12). The `()` is necessary when you want to choose who the `*` or `?` will affect. They also form groups, accessible through `$1`. No need to be sorry. Feel free to ask. If I can help, I gladly will.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

```
return myObj.mask.test(value)
```

Comment: I think it's wrong answer(either @user1671639's too). OP wants to test that "if string contains any character not matching above regex". So `'abcd#'` should be false since it contains `'#'`.

Comment: Thanks for response, but if value contains even one special character like $%^#, then will it return false?

Comment: yes Sagar it will. I am assuming u want abc# to return false. That's exactly what it will do. abc will return true. I am only telling u how to test a regex, not reformatting it